# How do I use UI button to call a new controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I've got an instance of a button and I also have two textfields for usernames and passwords. it is a test app therefor I have hard coded usernames and password and passed strings into it as such

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!

let username = "itishim"
let password = "password"
```

I just created a new view controller (viewcontroller2), drag it to story board and controlled dragged the main view controller to the new view controller. My goal is to use the button to segue to the new view controller if the password I hardcoded is true.

```
    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {


    if usernameTextfield.text == username && passwordTextfield.text == password {


    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextView", sender: self)
    } else {
            print("nope")
```

I keep getting     "[UIViewController button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8731515400" even though I have the right username and password. I am new to swift and would appreciate any help I get. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like your IBAction is not correctly connected to your button in the storyboard via Touch Up Inside. Double check that connection, even severing it and reattaching, and try again. Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: I just disconnected through connection inspector and reconnected it again and It didn't work tho. is that what you mean?

Comment: it's crashing because it doesn't recognize the method being sent to the button. It's hard to diagnose storyboard issues without seeing the project. If you want to zip it and upload it somewhere I'll take a quick look and tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Could you please right click on your element  you have an extra outlet that doesn't link to anything, please post a screenshot to get more info to find out your problem.

Comment: I can't see figure out how to upload a screenshot in the comment section.. but here is a link to the zip file for the project. https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3winf5hpxrc0eu/cleepcam.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your zip file. It crashes even though there is no segue. I propose you built a new project. And do the following.

1. Drag a viewController and set it with a new SecondViewController.swift
2. Go to storyBoard and from the firstViewController make a segue to the secondviewController by draging from the first (yellow ) button at the top the secondViewCOntroller and click show.
3. Add your textFields and button
4. Add button action in viewCOntroller.
5. Click the segue in storyboard and give it name "nextView"

And then it the button function

```
 @IBAction func ButtonFuntion(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if usernameTextfield.text == username && passwordTextField.text == password{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextView", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this again but no luck still. The only difference is with the argument in the ButtonFunction

Comment: I just upgraded my Xcode and restarted it and everything seems to be fine. thanks everyone for the support.